# Recovering the center of a monoid from the Drinfeld center

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, braided-tensor-categories

The Drinfeld center construction is intended to be a categorification of the center of a monoid. It seems to be folklore (eg [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1856053/386744) or [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/193754/167503)) that when the Drinfeld center is taken over a monoid $M$ (viewed as a category $BM$ with one single object) the usual notion of the center of the monoid is recovered.

If we denote $\bullet$ to this unique object (so that $\mathrm{End}_{BM}(\bullet) =  \mathrm{Hom}_{BM}(\bullet, \bullet) =M$), then we are forced to define $\bullet \otimes  \bullet := \bullet$ and of course $\bullet$ must be the unit for the monoidal structure. However, a foundational property of monoidal categories is that for any such $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, 1)$,we have that $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(1)$ is a commutative monoid (eg Lemma 1.1 of  *Turaev, Vladimir; Virelizier, Alexis*, [**Monoidal categories and topological field theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-49834-8).)

Essentially this says that $BM$ cannot be monoidal unless $M$ is a commutative monoid. Then

> 1. Am I making a blunder or that interpretation is simply not true?
> 2. What is the correct statement that recovers the center of a monoid from the Drinfeld construction?

Comment: I think what we want is rather to see $M$ as a monoidal category whose objects are elements of $M$ and morphisms are identities.

Comment: The answer by AAK you point out is a bit misleading: there is a notion of center for an arbitrary category, the endomorphisms of the identity functor, which for $BM$ recover its classical center. Those two notions are closely related though.